# Why is closure not working in React? and why can't I spread a object in react return value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react FC. What I noticed is that when I use regular variables those variables won't get updated.

Example:

```
const GameItem = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  let isFollowing = false;
  let gg = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (async function fetchGameGroup() {
        const { payload } = await getAGameGroup(Number(id));
        const { isFollower, gameGroup } = payload;
        isFollowing = isFollower; <-========= THIS SHOULD UPDATE AFTER COMPONENT DID MOUNT
        gg = gameGroup; <-========= THIS SHOULD UPDATE AFTER COMPONENT DID MOUNT
      })();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {' '}
        GAME ITEM {id} {gg} {isFollowing}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Why is `gg` and `isFollowing` not showing anything? I still have a reference to `gg` and `isFollowing` - how come the closure here is not working?

---

To fix that above issue I used `useState` like:

```
const GameItem = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [isFollowerState, setFollowing] = useState(false);
  const [gameGroupState, setGameGroup] = useState({
    id: '',
    description: '',
    title: '',
    createdAt: '',
    usersGameGroup: []
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (async function fetchGameGroup() {
        const { payload } = await getAGameGroup(Number(id));
        const { isFollower, gameGroup } = payload;
        setFollowing(isFollower);
        setGameGroup(gameGroup);
      })();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(gameGroupState, null) <========== WORKING 
       {gameGroupState} <============== NOT WORKING
      {}
      <h1>
        {' '}
        GAME ITEM {id} {isFollowerState.toString()}{' '}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

but I have an issue though, the `gameGroupState` won't display as is, I just want to check whats the response. I have to use `JSON.stringify` why can't I just display it?

Comment: Plain objects alone can't be rendered, React doesn't know what to do with them - either use `JSON.stringify`, or make your own function that iterates over the object properties and values to display them as needed.

Comment: What if we dont what the data type is? it maybe a string, number, object, or an array.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is a fine choice then, since it can serialize any type of value (which isn't circular)